# github adding BOM (ÿþ) into xml file when using devtools for R

Tags: r, xml, byte-order-mark

I'm trying to use devtools to load a package from github into R. 
However, something is wrong with the encoding somewhere, and a ÿþ character (BOM) is being added to the xml files I'm trying to load.

Commands I'm trying to use:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
build_github_devtools()
```

my output:

```
> devtools::install_github("hadley/devtools")
Downloading GitHub repo hadley/devtools@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/devtools/zipball/master
Installing devtools
"C:/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/Elza  \
  LQD/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWYpb9X/devtools1ef05d1610ee/hadley-devtools-45cbc91"  \
  --library="C:/R-3.3.0/library" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'devtools' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/R-33~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c devtools.c -o devtools.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o devtools.dll tmp.def devtools.o -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/i386 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/R-33~1.0/bin/i386 -lR
installing to C:/R-3.3.0/library/devtools/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/R-33~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c devtools.c -o devtools.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o devtools.dll tmp.def devtools.o -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/R-33~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/R-3.3.0/library/devtools/libs/x64
Warning in file.copy(files, dest, overwrite = TRUE) :
  problem copying .\devtools.dll to C:\R-3.3.0\library\devtools\libs\x64\devtools.dll: Permission denied
** R
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
ARGUMENT 'LQD\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8QllEY\Rin18dc4da2527d' __ignored__

Error: unexpected symbol in "ÿþ<?xml version"
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ARGUMENT 'LQD\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8QllEY\Rin18dc24dda77' __ignored__
```

specific problem:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "ÿþ<?xml version"
```

Comment: The one other person on the net with the same error (not in R) is on a virus support forum and I noticed that for them it said something about trying to use a 64-bit app with a CPU that doesn't support 64-bit mode. Also possible file corruption. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sjPSy8Qk2ZcJ:www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/512840/my-c-drive-is-named-access-denied-i-cant-do-anything-but-get-online/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us   I ran your code (the first 3 lines) and I didn't get any error myself.

Comment: I also could not use the function `build_gituhub_devtools()` until I once used `find_rtools()`. After this function call I was able to use this function. But I don´t think this solves your problem. Nevertheless I want to commit this possibility.